Why the Text property is never empty in the CustomButton class?
In the constructor i set the Text property to be empty ""
this.Text = "";

I also tried string.Empty instead ""
but i keep see on the button after dragging it from the toolbox in form1 designer the text and also see in the solution explorer on the right in the Text property the text.
i tested and if i change the size and drag one of the buttons from the toolbox it does change the size, but the Text property is never set to be empty.
same if i drag from the toolbox the custom button 2 or 3 or 4.

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageTest
{
    public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        public enum ShapeType
        {
            Shape1,
            Shape2,
            Shape3,
            Shape4,
            Shape5 // Add more shapes as needed
        }

        public ShapeType ButtonShape { get; set; }

        public CustomButton()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.Text = "";
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);

            Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

            switch (ButtonShape)
            {
                case ShapeType.Shape1:
                    DrawShape1(g, pen);
                    break;
                case ShapeType.Shape2:
                    DrawShape2(g, pen);
                    break;
                case ShapeType.Shape3:
                    DrawShape3(g, pen);
                    break;
                case ShapeType.Shape4:
                    DrawShape4(g, pen);
                    break;
                case ShapeType.Shape5:
                    DrawShape5(g, pen);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DrawShape1(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            // Large rectangle with two small rectangles inside
            Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, mainRect);

            // Two inner rectangles (top and bottom)
            Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(mainRect.X, mainRect.Y, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height / 2);
            Rectangle bottomRect = new Rectangle(mainRect.X + mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Y, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, topRect);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, bottomRect);
        }

        private void DrawShape2(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            // Large rectangle split in half horizontally, with one half filled
            Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, mainRect);

            // Fill one side with color
            Rectangle sideRect = new Rectangle(mainRect.X + mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Y, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, sideRect);
        }

        private void DrawShape3(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            // Large rectangle with two smaller rectangles in lower half
            Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, mainRect);

            // Two inner rectangles (left and right on bottom)
            Rectangle leftRect = new Rectangle(mainRect.X, mainRect.Y + mainRect.Height / 2, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height / 2);
            Rectangle rightRect = new Rectangle(mainRect.X + mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Y + mainRect.Height / 2, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height / 2);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, leftRect);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rightRect);
        }

        private void DrawShape4(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            // Large rectangle with a smaller yellow square inside
            Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, mainRect);

            // Small square in center
            Rectangle smallSquare = new Rectangle(mainRect.X + mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Y + mainRect.Height / 2, mainRect.Width / 4, mainRect.Height / 4);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, smallSquare);
        }

        private void DrawShape5(Graphics g, Pen pen)
        {
            // Example of another shape layout - Adjust as needed
            Rectangle mainRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 40);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, mainRect);

            // Additional drawing for complex shapes
            // Use specific coordinates to replicate the exact pattern
            Rectangle topLeft = new Rectangle(mainRect.X, mainRect.Y, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height / 2);
            Rectangle bottomRight = new Rectangle(mainRect.X + mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Y + mainRect.Height / 2, mainRect.Width / 2, mainRect.Height / 2);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, topLeft);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, bottomRight);
        }
    }
}

and the class that inherit from the custombutton
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ImageTest
{
    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class ShapeButton : CustomButton
    {
        public ShapeButton()
        {
            this.ButtonShape = ShapeType.Shape1;
        }
    }

    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class Shape2Button : CustomButton
    {
        public Shape2Button()
        {
            this.ButtonShape = ShapeType.Shape2;
            this.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class Shape3Button : CustomButton
    {
        public Shape3Button()
        {
            this.ButtonShape = ShapeType.Shape3;
            this.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class Shape4Button : CustomButton
    {
        public Shape4Button()
        {
            this.ButtonShape = ShapeType.Shape4;
            this.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    // Add additional shapes as needed
}


The Text of a newly created Control is assigned by its Designer. Reflects the indexed name assigned to Field that references the instance. You can override the default behavior
